# Mocking out a specific method during a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm relatively new to unit testing, and brand new to Moq. I have been tasked with writing up some unit tests for some pre-existing code.

I am struggling with the following method, as it makes a call to `model.importing.RunJob`, which as the name suggests, kicks off a job.

Obviously, I don't want it to actually DO the job, I just want to know that it's called the method.

How would I go about achieving this (ideally avoiding any code changes):

```
public ActionResult ImportsAndLoads(ImportsAndLoadsViewModel importsAndLoadsModel)
{
    Initialise(importsAndLoadsModel);
    LoadData(importsAndLoadsModel);

    if (importsAndLoadsModel.ActionToPerform == "RunJob")
    {
        using (var model = new Model())
        {
            List<Message> lstMessage;
            model.importing.RunJob((Jobs)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Jobs), importsAndLoadsModel.SelectedJob), out lstMessage);
            importsAndLoadsModel.lstMessages = lstMessage;
        }
    }
    return View(importsAndLoadsModel);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible having `var model = new Model()` in this action. You could mock `Model` itself but you cannot mock this action in the way you want.

Comment: You could inject the `Model` via the factory pattern.  Then inject a factory into the code to allow for easy mocking.  If you cannot alter the code then there isn't going to be a nice and easy way to mock that method.

Comment: @Juharr - I CAN change the code if absolutely required, but the obvious preference from above is to avoid it where possible (even if not that practical).

Comment: You might be able to do something using Microsoft [Moles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff798446.aspx) in order to alter the behaviour of `Model`. I've never actually used it, but understand it can be used to mock classes that "you don't control" (or don't wish to change). However, I'd recommend refactoring your code under test slightly, to allow this dependency to be injected.

Comment: @Rob could you provide an example of how you'd achieve that with minimal refactoring?

Comment: @Sk93 would recommend following juharr's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments on your question, you can't really test your `ImportsAndLoads` method in isolation in its current form, using Moq.  If you are using a high enough version of Visual Studio, then you may be able to test the method using [Shims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx), however if you're not already using this in your project, it's probably not the right way to go.

As it stands, your code is a little confusing.  It's a bit weird having a class called `Model`, that you're creating, in order to access a property in order to call a `RunJob` method.  If this really is the code, then you might want to encourage the team to revisit the `Model` class.

One of the suggestions was that you inject your `Model` dependency instead of creating it (or inject a factory and call out to the factory for creation).  This would be the preferable way to go, however it's not a trivial change in approach and really your team needs to buy into it as an approach rather than you making the change as a one-off.

If you aren't using an IOC container already (AutoFac, CastleWindsor, Ninject), then you may want to consider using one.  They will make switching to dependency injection easier.  If you want to do it by hand, then you can do, but it's harder.

Without knowing about the structure of more of your classes, it's hard to give a complete example, but one approach might be the following:

```
// Create an importer interface
public interface IImporter {
    void RunJob(Jobs job, out List<Message> listMessages);
}

// Implement it in a concrete class
public class Importer : IImporter{

    public void RunJob(Jobs job, out List<Message> listMessages) {
        // Do whatever it is it does.
    }
}

// Modify the constructor of your controller to allow the IImporter
// interface to be injected.  Default to null if not supplied, so that
// it can still be crated without parameters by the default MVC plumbing
public class ImportController : Controller
{
    private IImporter _importer;
    public ImportController(IImporter importer = null) {
        // If importer not injected, created a concrete instance
        if (null == importer) {
            importer = new Importer();
        }
        // Save dependency for use in actions
        _importer = importer;
    }

    // Use the injected importer in your action, rather than creating a model
    public ActionResult ImportsAndLoads(ImportsAndLoadsViewModel importsAndLoadsViewModel)
    {
        List<Message> listMsgs;
        _importer.RunJob(Jobs.One, out listMsgs);
        importsAndLoadsViewModel.lstMessages = listMsgs;
        return View(importsAndLoadsViewModel);
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to write a test to validate that `importsAndLoadsViewModel` has been updated as expected, using a test like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestModelMessagesAreUpdatedFromJobRunner() {
    var mockImporter = new Mock<IImporter>();
    List<Message> expectedMessages = new List<Message>();

    mockImporter.Setup(x=>x.RunJob(It.IsAny<Jobs>(), out expectedMessages));

    var model = new ImportsAndLoadsViewModel();

    // Inject the mocked importer while constructing your controller
    var sut = new ImportController(mockImporter.Object);

    // call the action you're testing on your controller
    ViewResult response = (ViewResult)sut.ImportsAndLoads(model);

    // Validate the the model has been updated to have the messages
    // returned by the mocked importer.
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedMessages, 
                    ((ImportsAndLoadsViewModel)response.Model).lstMessages);
}
```

This is simplification of what would need to be done / tested to demonstrate an approach.  One of the issues to be aware of with injecting dependencies is that it's quite easy to end up creating abstractions of abstractions, pushing the actual logic deeper and deeper into your code, only to find that you've just pushed the problem deeper and that you still don't know how to test a particular piece of logic because in essence it hasn't changed.

Comment: that's a great example - thanks! We don't use any IOC framework here yet, but my job is to refactor this whole codebase, and I've free reign to utlize whatever I deem necessary. For now, I'll implement this by hand until I get all my unit tests in place, then go for a proper switch over to ninject. There's a lot of "err..." code in the project, so I'm not surprised you're already questioning it! Cheers!